# Check if a user is logged in when using Fetch API

Tags: javascript, github-pages, fetch-api

I have my UI pages hosted on github pages and I am connecting to my API hosted on Heroku using Fetch API. I make requests passing the option `credentials: 'include'` so I can receive a users login status.

On the server-side, I implemented a token based authentication system using JWT. The token generated is stored in a cookie with a HttpOnly flag so the cookie is not accessible by javascript on the client-side.

**My problem:**

I want the user to be redirected to the dashboard when the user attempts to visit the sign up or login page, as well as redirecting the user to the login page to login when they attempt to access a protected route as an unauthenticated user. How can I achieve this using Fetch API?

Comment: Add the redirect: ‘follow’ property value to the second argument to fetch and have your api return a 302 status code and a redirect url when the situation occurs.

Comment: Thank you for your response Doug Coburn. I want the api to be accessible to as many origins as I whitelist. Returning a particular redirect url (which will contain a particular domain) may not be suitable for this purpose, what do you think?

Comment: You could do redirect: “manual” and watch for the 302 status code response from fetch - and set the window.location value client side.  The api could set location to /dashboard and client side you could lookup the url for /dashboard to use as the redirect url. For example: const mapping = { “/dashboard”: “https://site/workbook” }